# How to color the background within the square HTML shape entity?

Tags: html, shapes

Using HTML I want to create a square inline with a black border and green background. I have been using the square shape entity in HTML `&#9633`. The issue is when I use the background-color style it fills the entire div. How do I get this shape with a black border and green just within the shape?

Below is what I have tried, but it ends up with coloring the entire div as green. Would love just to work with the shape and specify the coloring of the background only.

```html
<div style="font-size:60px;background-color:#388004;">&#9633;</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand with kind of figure you want to display. If the figure is too complex, maybe it is better to use a svg or an icon

Comment: A square: a green div with same height/width and a css black border? Couldn't you use that?

Comment: .... i think it is pretty clear what I want, I do not know how I could possibly be more clear.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Your current code.*

```html
<div style="font-size:60px;background-color:#388004;">&#9633;</div>
```

If my understanding is correct, you want a box or square with *black* border and *filled* with green color.

I don't know if this could help you, but if that so...
Make another `div` that will fill the your `&#9633;` or box and remove the `background-color` in the parent `div`.

Using a static css, you can do like this.

```html
<div style="position:relative;font-size:60px;">
  <div style="position:absolute;top:30px;left:6px;width:23.5px;height:23.5px;background-color:#388004;"></div>
  &#9633;
</div>
```

But, if you just want a box with black border filled with green color and this `&#9633;` is not required, you can actually do it with just one `div` by setting up it's `border`.

```html
<div style="border:2px solid black;width:23px;height:23px;background-color:#388004;"></div>
```

Comment: yup this exactly what I wanted, second answer was great! thanks